# Why does my Python user input code not consider the input correct

Tags: python, user-input

I am new to coding and want to train and do my own thing with user inputs. The User Input code does not work. It is a number guessing game. When I guess the right number, it says "Incorrect".

```
import random

while True:
    intro = input("Hello! Want to play a game?(Y or N)")
    if intro.lower() == "y" or intro.lower() == "yes":
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print("Let's play a number-guessing game!")
            max_num_in = input("Pick a big number")
            max_num = int(max_num_in)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            min_num_in = input("Now pick a smaller number")
            min_num = int(min_num_in)
            rndm_num = int(random.randrange(min_num,max_num,1))
            print(rndm_num)
            rndm_in = input("Guess a number between the maximum and minumum numbers!")

            if rndm_num == rndm_in:
                print("Whoo hoo! You did it! You guessed the number! The number was" + str(rndm_num))
            elif rndm_in != rndm_num:
                print("Whoops, wrong number. Please try again.(Trials left = 2)")
                rndm_in1 = input("Guess again!")
                if rndm_in1 == rndm_num:
                    print("Whoo hoo! You did it! You guessed the number! The number was" + str(rndm_num))
                elif rndm_in1 != rndm_num:
                    print("You didn't get it right. Please try again (Trials left = 1)")
                    rndm_in2 = input("Guess again!")
                    if rndm_in2 == rndm_num:
                        print("Whoo Hoo! You finally did it! The number was" + str(rndm_num))
                    elif rndm_in2 != rndm_num:
                        print("Incorrect. The number was " + str(rndm_num))
    elif intro.lower() == "n" or intro.lower() == "no":
        print("Alright. Bye")
```

Comment: I put in the right number, however the code says "Incorrect"...

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are strings convert them to int by using int() function
"5"!=5

Comment: You should also try using while loop for this as well

Answer (score 0):

This one looks suspicious:

```
if rndm_num == rndm_in:
```

It looks like you getting a **str** as *rndm_in* but your *rndm_num* is an **int**.

Try:

```
if rndm_num == int(rndm_in):
```